# Show geometry of constant size on a canvas irrespective zoomed in/out

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a canvas which shows a surface, and there is an option to mark some points on the surface. These points are displayed as stars using the PathGeometry object(which means I have computed the points and created a polyline), the size of the star increases/decreases as we zoom in/out.

Now I want to make the size of the star always constant irrespective of zooming.

Is there a way to achieve this, like modifying the stroke shape or something?

Comment: How do you are increasing the zoom?

Comment: Get the zoom level of your device and adjust scale of your stars?